# Create Calendar with Pivot or function in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get a calendar with this structure from my AUT_CALENDAR table?

[image]

I am applying PIVOT to obtain a calendar with the following query.
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bbb88230f3377c17f79bca43599296d)

```
SELECT IDCALENDARIO,NombreDia, [Lunes], [Martes], [Miercoles], [Jueves], [Viernes], [Sabado], [Domingo]
FROM (
    SELECT IDCALENDARIO,NombreDia, DATENAME(dw, FECHA) AS DayWeek, DIA
    FROM AUT_CALENDARIO
    WHERE FECHA between '2022-02-01' and '2022-02-28'
    ) AS src
    pivot (
        sum(DIA) FOR DayWeek IN ([Lunes], [Martes], [Miercoles], [Jueves], [Viernes], [Sabado], [Domingo])
    ) AS pvt
```

**But the result is not what I expected**

This is my result when executing the mentioned PIVOT

[image]

And what I want is to get a calendar as follows:

[image]

So, do you have any other ideas how to get this required result if a PIVOT is maybe some function or stored procedure is used or my table structure is wrong, any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: I have created the table and execute the indicated pivot and a calendar is created from Monday to Sunday            :   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bbb88230f3377c17f79bca43599296d

Comment: Please populate the table in your Fiddle link, as it's not usable to reproduce your situation with no data in it. I would not expect anyone to put in the extra effort of writing the inserts on their own to populate the able, just for the sake of answering your question. Try to remove as much friction as possible, and more people will be likely to offer you help.